# Recommandations with SVD

Tags: svd, recommendation-engine

I'm actually in an intern ship at LIRIS (Computer Science Research Laboratory) and I work on recommender systems. My intern ship supervisor asks me to make a presentation about recommending movies thanks to SVD for tomorrow. So I learned about that.

I think that I understood the mathematical part with the A = US(V^T) but some things are not really clear for me for the next step (recommend movies). I've found an amount of knowledge and it's not clear in my head :D

I don't understand if the SVD calculates the numbers which are missing in the matrix A (predict ratings for users who haven't rate a film) or if we need a dense matrix A that we factorize in 3 matrices to recommend movies ?

For the first case, how it works ? Because I've found nothing about that...
For the second, how can 3 matrices can help us to recommend movies ? I don't understand the link between a decomposed matrix and recommend movies.

I will be very thankful if someone can help me :)

PS : sorry for the English, I'm a French student :D

Comment: You can find a couple of examples online for the same problem, [this one](https://alyssaq.github.io/2015/20150426-simple-movie-recommender-using-svd/) might be helpful

Comment: @Signo thanks for your comment. I've already read this article but I will read it a second time :) Sometimes I found on Internet that SVD calculates the numbers which are missing, sometimes that SVD recommend items... That's why I'm a little lost ;)

Comment: as far as I remember that depends on the approach you're using, you could either ignore the rows with missing values, or fill the missing data using an imputation procedure. Check [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-December/027590.html) and [this](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/KDD-cup-2007/proceedings/missing-value-Kurucz.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're referring to is called the matrix completion problem. For a library you can see [here.](https://github.com/tonyduan/matrix-completion) The method is called [singular value thresholding](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.3286) or alternating least squares. An alternative implementation is [here.](http://www.quuxlabs.com/blog/2010/09/matrix-factorization-a-simple-tutorial-and-implementation-in-python/) The code is available [here](http://www.quuxlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/mf.py_.txt)